# Inverse of function with two x's

Tags: inverse, inverse-function

So I'm trying to take the inverse of this function

$$y = x + e^x$$

I've tried switching the x's and y's and then isolate the y using a natural log. But, I can't figure out how to get the y isolated after the switch and natural log. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! The existence of an inverse does not necesarily mean that it can be nicely computed. Seems we have such a case here.

Comment: $x=y-W(e^y)$ where $W$ is the Lambert W.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = e^x + x$. Then $f'(x) = e^x + 1 > 0$ which means that $f$ is strictly increasing and thus injective. Is it surjective? Well, $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty}f(x) = \pm\infty$, so, yes, by intermediate value theorem. So, we know that $f$ is invertible. Trouble is that the inverse can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions. We need [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) (do read examples on wiki, they are quite instructive).

So, \begin{align}
x+e^x = y &\implies xe^{-x}+1 = ye^{-x}\\
&\implies (y-x)e^{-x} = 1\\
&\implies (y-x)e^{y-x} = e^y\quad \small\text{(apply Lambert $W$)}\\
&\implies y-x = W(e^y)\\
&\implies x = y - W(e^y)
\end{align}
Hence, $f^{-1}(x) = x-W(e^x)$.

Lambert $W$ is not an elementary function and one should use numerical methods to compute particular values, but then again, it's the same for $\sin$ or $\ln$.